# Website with easy URL to retrieve profile pictures for LinkedIn, Facebook and Twitter

Tags: api, social-networking, image

I'm sorry if this is not specifically code-related. I came across a website a month ago or so which provides an incredible easy way to obtain a user's profile picture for various social network (I believe only LinkedIn, Facebook and Twitter was supported), but I cannot for the life of me remember the site.

The URLs they provided were something like `[URL].com/linkedin/:id` and `[URL].com/twitter/:username`.

If anyone has it bookmarked or knows what I am talking about, I'd love a link to the site. I've Googled lots of combinations to try and find the site and scoured my browsing history, but I just haven't been able to find it :(

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds very interesting and curious myself how that site works

Answer (score 0):

This is the only service that comes to mind, Incarnate

http://visitmix.com/work/incarnate/

Is that the one?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :( But thanks for answering!